# How can I start a Java process using WinRM through Java?

Tags: java, spring, powershell, winrm

So essentially from inside of a spring-boot API, I need to start up a different spring-boot API remotely.

On the remote machine I need to:

1. Start the spring-boot application from a jar file on a remote Windows machine.
2. Return the PID of the running jar
3. Return this PID into the local API code to commit to database

I am successfully able to connect to the remote machine using this library: https://github.com/juniperus/remotepowershell and running commands works fine, but no matter which commands I try for running the jar, the remote powershell session will not terminate until the java program has (which causes it to hang).

The closest I have come is

```
(Start-Process -passthru -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardOutput '.\console.out' -RedirectStandardError '.\console.err' -FilePath java -ArgumentList @('-jar C:\xxx.jar')).ID
```

But despite perfect functionality on a local machine, the session does not terminate and return PID in the Java code.

I have also tried a different remote powershell library with the same result.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered simply using containers?

Comment: Since you specify WinRM, you could try running this powershell command locally: `Invoke-WmiMethod –ComputerName Remote01 -Class win32_process -Name create -ArgumentList "java -jar C:\xxx.jar" | select -exp ProcessId`. Or you could look into running a background process with `Start-Job`

Comment: You could you install the spring boot app as a windows service and start and stop that service.  See https://eric-ndirangu.medium.com/deploying-a-springboot-application-jar-as-a-windows-service-using-winsw-75314f21d667

Comment: I just want to say that I am currently solving this problem by running the powershell command through ssh instead of WinRM. The java remote powershell library was not able to detect termination of the command no matter what I tried, but jsch allowed me to wait for certain characters and terminate the session on command.

Comment: Have you already tried without `-NoNewWindow`? Maybe you can simply add `;exit` to the end of the remote command? I'm not familiar with the java library, but do you have to check the session status manually?

Comment: Did you try with winrm4j?